# Instagram Basic Display API - Video Poster Compression - thumbnail_url

Tags: instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

Is there a way to compress or get a smaller version of the image when making calls to Instagram API?

If the `media_type === 'IMAGE'`, I can get various different image sizes so that they load quicker, but with `media_type === 'VIDEO'` I can only get the `thumbnail_url` which will display a URL like this:

[Thumbnail URL from Instagram Image](https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.36329-15/341331399_1197821827537272_4699957687994969180_n.jpg?_nc_cat=106&ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=8ae9d6&_nc_ohc=Ke5_Q666utgAX_-MrCH&_nc_ht=scontent.cdninstagram.com&edm=ANo9K5cEAAAA&oh=00_AfB-dnfGuajxlSpDyX6I6_CG_suTfEcjgQyqzBN5VyX9kA&oe=646B4C98&w=0)

If I check the same image on Instagram I can see there are much smaller images such as this one:

[Same Image but from the Instagram website](https://instagram.flis6-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/341331399_1197821827537272_4699957687994969180_n.jpg?stp=c0.997.2565.2565a_dst-jpg_e15_s320x320&_nc_ht=instagram.flis6-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=100&_nc_ohc=bgqjvqFCXw4AX_7UpQA&edm=AOQ1c0wBAAAA&ccb=7-5&oh=00_AfDN2-jKR3IMwGJyHp8O88nKhYPjBzCsCmOLoCYgwBinGA&oe=64690565&_nc_sid=f70a57)

This issue it's causing is that it's slowing down the speed of my website so ideally I want to load a lower resolution version of the image to increase the speed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Technically when the media type is `'VIDEO'`, the Instagram API only provides the thumbnail url, so unfortunately you cannot directly obtain smaller versions of videos like you can with images.

However, I found something that may work. Basically, when you get the video_url if you can get the id of the video (for that you can use a regular expression based on the language you are using), and then you can obtain a lower resolution by doing something like this:

- Original video URL: `https://instagram.com/p/{video_id}/videos/{video_id}.mp4`
- Lower-resolution video URL: `https://instagram.com/p/{video_id}/videos/{video_id}/low_resolution.mp4`

Hope it serves you

Comment: Thanks, but the video is not an issue as such, it's more related to the poster image for the video.